# Can we suspend a process inside a system call?

Tags: kernel, system-calls

Suppose I created a system call ABC.

```
syscall ABC()
{
  int mask = disable(); // to disable interupt
  ....

  pid // pid of calling process

  if(some condition){
      suspend(pid);
  }

  ....

  restore(mask); // restore interupts
}
```

If invoke ABC from our program and due to some criteria, ABC system call has to call suspend. Then what will happen?
As interrupts are disabled, no other process can context switch and a current process is in suspend state. In a single core processor, is it a hanging state ? Because there is no process to resume the current process.
Please correct me if i am wrong.

Instead of suspend can we use sleep. Is there any difference, while making a change.

Comment: What API do you plan to use in order to suspend your process?

Comment: Actually, I didn't mention the OS. It is "Xinu" which is very much similar to Linux but not that extensible (mainly for the academic purpose). And I am working in Xinu system (kernel), so there is suspend.c file (API), which contains suspend function(that is directly accessing the process table and accessing its entry).

Answer (score 0):

Suspending the current process will *cause* an immediate context switch. 
Interrupt masking is a part of context,
so the context switch will cause normal interrupt handling to resume.

Of course sleep is different from suspend
in that suspend is much more visible at user level. 
A process that’s sleeping
is almost indistinguishable from a process that’s running
(unless you look at `ps`, `/proc`, `top`, or other monitoring tools). 
A process that’s suspended
looks like it’s half-dead (`wait()` in the parent returns). 
Any signal (that’s not being blocked or ignored)
can wake a sleeping process,
but only `SIGCONT` can resume a suspended process. 
(Even `SIGTERM` will leave a suspended process suspended,
but `SIGKILL` will kill it.)